# Best way to index and save large xarray dataset and write to file

Tags: python, indexing, python-xarray, file-writing

I have ocean model data which is very large and split over multiple data files. Files are split by time, generally into monthly blocks. They could contain monthly averages (1 time index) or multiple (daily -- varying time index). The data has four dimensions: (time, x, y and z).

For comparison to observations I need to interpolate this data in both space and time. I'm using a nearest neighbour approach and have identified the indices of the nearest points (x and y) and the nearest times. So this amounts to a 3 dimensional indexing of a large dimensional array. I want to then save this indexed data to file (and cannot read it all to disk since it is so large).

I am indexing using `xarray.dataset.isel()` on a dataset opened using `xarray.open_mfdataset` with chunking enabled (so Dask). The data is chunked in time.

When I call `to_netcdf()`, this incredibly (and unreasonably) slow for large numbers of points. The time taken also doesn't increase linearly with the number of points. It is likely to have on the order of 10s of thousands of points to extract from the model data.

Is this the correct approach or is there a better way to do this? Some example code below:

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xarray.open_mfdataset(filenames, chunks={'time':5}, cache=True)
# Get X, Y and time indices 
ind_x, ind_y, ind_t = indices_function()

#Index the data
indexed = ds.isel(x=ind_x, y=ind_y, time=ind_t)

#Write the data to file
indexed.to_netcdf(file_out)
```

Comment: What do `ind_x`, `ind_y` and `ind_t` look like ? Can you check `indexed` is really the shape you expected (before calling `to_netcdf`) ?

Comment: `ind_x`, `ind_y` and `ind_t` are all 1 dimensional DataArrays. They were created from numpy arrays by just calling something similar to `xr.DataArray(ind_x_numpy)`. They are all of the same length.

The code works so I have tested this for small numbers of indices. `indexed` in these cases looks as expected. i.e. a new `dim_0`, which is the indexed dimension and the original retained `z` dimension.

Comment: it seems like you're doing this correctly. if the data is chunked in time then you'll need to read all of the data touched by `ind_t`. generally, using advanced indexing like this across chunks is slow. There's a lot of activity happening in this part of xarray all the time - make sure your version of the package is up to date. But otherwise, I'd maybe do this in chunks. First pull the subset of the data needed by selecting with numpy arrays, then load the result and reindex with DataArray indices. Good luck!

Comment: otherwise, a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with a large dataset you make on the fly and a minimal code example would be super helpful to see if there are concrete tips we can offer

Comment: Thanks for this response. I will put together a minimal reproducible example when next at PC. In the meantime I'm thinking about your suggestion of loading chunks manually and indexing them then. The problem is that it is conceivable that the indexed dataset is also very large (unlikely but possible). Is it possible to append each indexed chunk to file as I go using xarray? I dont think to_netcdf can append along a dimension. I guess I may need to use a more hands on library for this.